# Row level security only on SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-level-security

I am enabling Row level security on a table. I want the row security only on SELECT. So that other users can insert and update their respective records.
I am using postgreSQL and I am pretty much beginner for 'ROW-LEVEL-SECURITY'. I am trying it with following commands. Please update if I am mixing PSQL and MySQL commands. or any better way to achieve it.

```
ALTER TABLE important_table ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

It works fine but then when I specify for select,

```
ALTER TABLE important_table SET ROW SECURITY FOR SELECT;
```

I get error with it:

```
Error: syntax error at or near "ROW"
```

Comment: psql is a command line client for Prostgres and not a synonym for it. I changed the tags for you.

Comment: Thanks :) my bad

Comment: Once you have enabled row level security, use [`CREATE POLICY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createpolicy.html) to create a policy for `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks. It has worked. I was mistakenly using Policy `FOR ALL`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe could you please provide your comment as answer, so kahldi could accept it?

Comment: I don't think that's enough for an answer, and I don't feel like writing up some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Laurenz Albe, we have to create Policy for required privileges like For and Update. Once Policy is created, Row level security will work for mentioned previledges.

Comment: Hi. This is a comment, and not an answer. :-) Can you copy the text to your question and delete this "answer"? Regards

Comment: @kometen.. than how can I accept the answer and mark the question solved? do you recommend me deleting it anyways?

Comment: Aah, I may have misunderstood your answer to your own question as a comment. If this solves your problem you can leave it as it is. Regards